# Searching for several exact substrings in one String

Tags: vba, excel, search, excel-formula

I have a problem I've been working on for a while but cannot seem to get there. I have a list of about 6000 material descriptions and I want to pull out a specific searched for word.

So if the description is 'Handschuhe-Wunder-20XV28', and the search word was 'Wunder', this material would then have a new column that said 'Wunder'. However, I might also want to search for the word 'Super', and I would like this to appear in the same column.

This search would only pick up the exact words, so if it was looking for 'Super', it wouldn't return a result if it found the word 'Superman'.

I had a formula which can do this:

```
=IF(AQ2=1,IF(SUM(IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(Search!A$2, K2)), IF(COUNT((IF(CODE(MID(K2, SEARCH(Search!A$2, K2)-1, 1))>122, 1, "")), (IF(CODE(MID(K2, SEARCH(Search!A$2, K2)-1, 1))<65, 1, "")), (IF(SEARCH(Search!A$2, K2)-1<1, 1, ""))), IF(COUNT((IF(CODE(MID(K2, SEARCH(Search!A$2, K2)+LEN(Search!A$2), 1))>122, 1, "")), (IF(CODE(MID(K2, SEARCH(Search!A$2, K2)+LEN(Search!A$2), 1))<65, 1, "")), (IF((SEARCH(Search!A$2, K2)+LEN(Search!A$2)+1)>LEN(K2), 1, ""))), 1, 0), 0), 0))>0,Search!A$2,0),"")
```

Where AQ2 contained the initial quick search:

```
=IF(IFERROR(SEARCH(Search!$A$2,'Raw Data Working'!K2),0)=0,"",1)
```

This was to improve efficiency as the first formula separates non-alphanumerical characters to find the exact word, after the second formula I posted works out whether it is worth search at all.

I tried recording this in visual basic, with the idea that there would be columns increasing as part of a for loop, with two columns for each search item. I would then somehow bring across the results of any searches into one column. However, when I record the long formula in VBA, despite including breaks, it still does not work.

I would be grateful for any help, suggestions or ideas. Quite simply, it is looking in one piece of text, to see whether the text includes either of several works. And they would have to be exact matches.

Thanks everyone!

Comment: I would do this in VBA. It would require looping through the column and applying one, or several string search functions. Can you post the code you tried and explain what isn't working?

Comment: Is every search term separated by dashes '-' ?

Comment: Consider the use of Regular Expressions...

Comment: VBA is always faster. ;-)

Comment: Thanks everyone so far with you help, I must apologize as I didn't make it clear. Not all words are separated by "-". Some are simply 'handschuhe super 20X', some are 'handschuhe/super:20X', etc. Basically there is always either a space, or a non-alphanumerical character between every word.

Comment: Just to refer back to what Kyle mentioned, I literally recording the working formula above (the long one) as a macro, tried this several times, and Excel doesn't seem to want to run it as a macro.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on what has been discussed, the following should meet your needs or at least be a lot closer to what you imagine.

---

**First is a function that accepts all the characters you wish to delimit the string with:**

Note: This function is actually kind of awesome.

> ```
> Function MultiSplitX(ByVal SourceText As String, RemoveBlankItems As Boolean, ParamArray Delimiters()) As String()
>     Dim a As Integer, b As Integer, n As Integer
>     Dim i As Integer: i = 33
>     Dim u As Variant, v As Variant
>     Dim tempArr() As String, finalArr() As String, fDelimiters() As String
>
>     If InStr(TypeName(Delimiters(0)), "()") <> 0 And LBound(Delimiters) = UBound(Delimiters) Then
>         ReDim fDelimiters(LBound(Delimiters(0)) To UBound(Delimiters(0))) 'If passing array vs array items then
>         For a = LBound(Delimiters(0)) To UBound(Delimiters(0))            'build that array
>             fDelimiters(a) = Delimiters(0)(a)
>         Next a
>     Else
>         fDelimiters = Delimiters(0)
>     End If
>
>     Do While InStr(SourceText, Chr(i)) <> 0 'Find an unused character
>         i = i + 1
>     Loop
>
>     For a = LBound(fDelimiters) To UBound(fDelimiters) 'Sort Delimiters by length
>         For b = a + 1 To UBound(fDelimiters)
>             If Len(fDelimiters(a)) < Len(fDelimiters(b)) Then
>                 u = fDelimiters(b)
>                 fDelimiters(b) = fDelimiters(a)
>                 fDelimiters(a) = u
>             End If
>         Next b
>     Next a
>
>     For Each v In fDelimiters 'Replace Delimiters with a common character
>         SourceText = Replace(SourceText, v, Chr(i))
>     Next
>
>     tempArr() = Split(SourceText, Chr(i)) 'Remove empty array items
>     If RemoveBlankItems = True Then
>         ReDim finalArr(LBound(tempArr) To UBound(tempArr))
>         n = LBound(tempArr)
>         For i = LBound(tempArr) To UBound(tempArr)
>             If tempArr(i) <> "" Then
>                 finalArr(n) = tempArr(i)
>                 n = n + 1
>             End If
>         Next i
>         n = n - 1
>         ReDim Preserve finalArr(LBound(tempArr) To n)
>
>         MultiSplitX = finalArr
>     Else: MultiSplitX = tempArr
>     End If
>     Erase finalArr
>     Erase tempArr
> End Function
> ```

---

**Next is the routine that finds all applicable matches:**

```
Sub SearchDynamicDelimit()
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(2)
    Dim strTest As New Collection
    Dim udRange As Range: Set udRange = ws.Range("D2", ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp)) '<~~Change to your Search Range
    Dim myCell, myMatch, myString, i, delimiter, d, s, t, u, c
    Dim temp() As String, myDelimiter() As String, delNotInSearch() As String, delInSearch() As String, tempCell As String
    Dim delimitInSearch As Boolean: delimitInSearch = False
    Dim delString As String, searchString As String

    For Each myMatch In udRange
        If myMatch.Value <> "" Then strTest.Add myMatch.Value
        searchString = searchString & CStr(myMatch.Value)
        Debug.Print myMatch.Value & " " & myMatch.Address
    Next myMatch

    ws.Range("B2", ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "B")).Clear '<~~Change to where you want the results to populate

    delString = "_|-|.|/|<|>|;|:|[|]|\|{|}| |(|,|)" '<~~Change to the delimiters you want. Separate them with any unique character.
    myDelimiter() = Split(delString, "|") '<~~Make sure the unique character you chose above is the same here.

    ReDim delNotInSearch(LBound(myDelimiter) To UBound(myDelimiter))
    ReDim delInSearch(LBound(myDelimiter) To UBound(myDelimiter))
    t = LBound(myDelimiter)
    u = LBound(myDelimiter)
    For s = LBound(myDelimiter) To UBound(myDelimiter)
        If InStr(searchString, myDelimiter(s)) = 0 Then
            delNotInSearch(t) = myDelimiter(s)
            Debug.Print "delNotInSearch(" & t & ") = " & delNotInSearch(t)
            t = t + 1
        Else
            delInSearch(u) = myDelimiter(s)
            Debug.Print "delInSearch(" & u & ") = " & delInSearch(u)
            u = u + 1
        End If
    Next s
    t = t - 1
    u = u - 1
    If t <> -1 Then ReDim Preserve delNotInSearch(LBound(myDelimiter) To t)
    If u <> -1 Then ReDim Preserve delInSearch(LBound(myDelimiter) To u)

    If delInSearch(LBound(delInSearch)) <> "" Then delimitInSearch = True

    If strTest.Count > 0 Then
        For Each myCell In ws.Range("A2", ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp)) '<~~Change to range being searched
            If myCell.Value = "" Then GoTo SkipBlanks
                If delimitInSearch = True Then
                    temp() = MultiSplitX(myCell.Value, True, delNotInSearch())

                    For i = 0 To UBound(temp)
                        For Each myString In strTest
                            If StrComp(temp(i), myString, vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
                                If ws.Range("B" & myCell.Row).Value = "" Then   'If you only want it to show 1 search result, remove the IF statement entirely
                                    ws.Range("B" & myCell.Row).Value = temp(i)  'And keep this line only. Change "B" to where you want the results to go
                                Else: ws.Range("B" & myCell.Row).Value = ws.Range("B" & myCell.Row).Value & ", " & temp(i)
                                End If
                            End If
                        Next myString
                    Next i
                    Erase temp
                End If
                temp() = MultiSplitX(myCell.Value, True, delInSearch())
                For i = 0 To UBound(temp)
                    For Each myString In strTest
                        If StrComp(temp(i), myString, vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
                            If ws.Range("B" & myCell.Row).Value = "" Then   'If you only want it to show 1 search result, remove the IF statement entirely
                                ws.Range("B" & myCell.Row).Value = temp(i)  'And keep this line only. Change "B" to where you want the results to go
                            Else: ws.Range("B" & myCell.Row).Value = ws.Range("B" & myCell.Row).Value & ", " & temp(i)
                            End If
                        End If
                    Next myString
                Next i
                Erase temp
SkipBlanks:
        Next myCell

    Else: MsgBox "Nothing found to search...", Title:="No Search Item"
    End If
End Sub
```

---

**On my sample workbook, I yielded the following results using the routine in conjuction with the MultiSplit function:**

[image]

*Notice `Sich.Okay` was properly found, even though `"."` being used as a delimiter.*

+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

## **ORIGINAL ANSWER BELOW FOR THOSE IT MAY HELP**

If you want a method using VBA you could try something like this:

```
Sub ColorMatchingString()
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)
    Dim strTest As Collection: Set strTest = New Collection
    Dim udRange As Range: Set udRange = ws.Range("E1:G1") 'Define Search Ranges
    Dim myCell, myMatch, myString, i, nextRR As Long
    Dim temp() As String, tempLength As Integer, stringLength As Integer

    nextRR = 3

    For Each myMatch In udRange 'Build the collection with Search Range Values
        strTest.Add myMatch.Value
    Next myMatch
    If ws.Range("E1").Value <> "" Or ws.Range("F1").Value <> "" Or ws.Range("G1").Value <> "" Then
        For Each myCell In ws.Range("A1:A50")
            temp() = Split(myCell.Text, "-")
            startLength = 0
            stringLength = 0
            For i = 0 To UBound(temp)
                tempLength = Len(temp(i))
                stringLength = stringLength + tempLength + 2
                For Each myString In strTest
                    If StrComp(temp(i), myString, vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
                        ws.Range("H" & nextRR).Value = myCell.Text
                        ws.Range("I" & nextRR).Value = myCell.Address
                        startLength = stringLength - tempLength - 2
                        ws.Range("H" & nextRR).Characters(startLength, tempLength).Font.Color = vbRed
                        nextRR = nextRR + 1
                    End If
                Next myString
            Next i
            Erase temp
        Next myCell
    Else: MsgBox "Nothing found to search...", Title:="No Search Item"
    End If
End Sub
```

What this will do is find your search items and show them in a new column, as well as show you where the item was found.

[image]

Comment: Hi Tyeler, thank you for taking the time to do this so far. However, I haven't been able to replicate your results with the same data set, I merely get the error message you inserted. Also, while I can imagine this would be of some use to me, I notice in your code you state 'E1', 'F1', etc. As the problem I have is searching for 800 items, I simply cannot expand this bit manually, do you have any suggestions? Also, it would probably be more useful to me if it just brings out the word it found, so I could easily filter the results column. Thanks for your help so far!

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what your problem is, granted, when I wrote this I didn't see your comment about there being no set delimitation. I also don't think I understand the scope. You just want to see how many times a search word comes up? Also, the code above isn't tailored specifically to what you need. It's the idea. You would either have to be very descriptive on what you desire, or edit the code to meet your needs. I can't imagine this code wouldn't work for you with a couple minor changes.....

Comment: You also say that you can't expand the search field manually. Why? How are you getting the search words? Are they randomly scattered about?

Comment: It's a little difficult to describe. I have a list of 800 Brands, and a list of 16,000 Material Descriptions. We want classify the Materials better, so we wish to add the brands as a separate column, so that we can pivot table etc. to see spend on a particular brand. So whichever Brand name is found in the free text description, we want as a new column whereby the brand name is on the same row as the original description, as I said for use in a pivot table.

Comment: So if we have the brands 'Apple','Windows' and 'Linux' that we want to find, the column on the left is what we have, and the one on the right is what we want:

Material Description           //                Brand /
Apple Mac 128GB               //                Apple /
Windows PC/i5                     //                Windows /
Bananas                                // /
Linux/Software87XV             //                Linux /
Pineapple                                 

The last one is an example of it has to be the full exact word, so it doesn't classify a pineapple as an apple.

Comment: The // indicate a new column, and there are two columns per row

Comment: I get what you're trying to do now. Give me a minute and I'll adjust the code for you

Comment: @ChengShi I've updated the code to include what we discussed.

Comment: Actually, let me change the code so it's pivot table friendly. Can you include a picture of your spreadsheet in your question with the "Brand" column too? Doesn't need to be the full sheet, just the applicable portions (Search field, Brand, Description)

Comment: Hi Tyeler, this is 100% what I was looking for in terms of results, but even when I copy your items it won't run. I noticed you defined the sheet number which I have accounted for, but it simply will not run. I'm very confused :/

Comment: Also, it looks exactly like the one you sent, except the descriptions are in column K, the brands would appear in L. The search terms were actually on a separate sheet.

Comment: None, simply nothing happens. I click run, the screen briefly flashes but nothing happens

Comment: Or that Sheet(2) is out of range. As well as your error message.

Comment: At the top, change ws to `Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("your sheet name"). See if that doesn't fix it.

Comment: Forget that, worked out how to do it. Final issue I believe is I searched for something but it didn't appear as it was 'sich.' and I searched 'sich', do I need to add another replace bit in the code?

Comment: If you want to see both projects as I wrote them, you can [download my excel file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/q5fnc3ccx7hl6k3/Search%20and%20List.xlsm?dl=0) and play around with the working versions there.

Comment: oh, yea you would if you have decimals/periods. `tempCell = Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(myCell.Text, " ", "-"), "/", "-"), "_", "-"), ":", "-"), ".", "-")`

Comment: This comma error is persisting though, it keeps adding hundreds of commas. How can I stop this? I had fixed it, but it's come back?

Comment: Well, I would need to see how you manipulated the code to tell you why it's happening. Are you able to replicate this from my excel file? Or is it only in your own?

Comment: It's when I add in the extra replace for the full stop that I get loads of commas in the results row, albeit after the correct word

Comment: That is literally it, the raw file you uploaded albeit with the naming change at the top, works fine, except for the not picking up 'sich.' when I search for 'sich'. It's adding in the extra replace that ruins it.

Comment: Copy paste this over `tempCell`:  tempCell = Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(myCell.Text, " ", "-"), "/", "-"), "_", "-"), ":", "-"), ".", "-")

Comment: On my program, [I can't replicate the issue you're having](http://puu.sh/rxtrF/1b51ce6a25.png). I've tried about 20 different ways to make it produce excess commas (or anything for that matter) and it simply won't...

Comment: Yes it doesn't make sense, because your code moves on once it adds the comma for two vendors. I'm at a loss to work it out...

Comment: Can you upload your file?

Comment: I'm afraid I can't as it is all classified. I can just say that when I add the comma bit, it suddenly slows down, and adds several hundred commas after some words in the results

Comment: Try this then: In the module, click anywhere in the code and press F8. Step through every single line and iteration until it starts that comma repeating thing. When it does, look at the values of all of the variables and see if you can make sense of what it's doing wrong. Can you at least paste the "Description" line that is returning a billion commas? You can change the words up if it's classified, I really just want to see the format. I'd like to recreate what you're seeing on my end.

Comment: Another thing we could try is changing `tempCell` to this: `tempCell = Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(myCell.Text, " ", "-"), "/", "-"), "_", "-"), ":", "-"), Chr(46), "-")`

Comment: Ok, I've looked at my code again, and when I search for 'SMC', it doesn't recognize  VALVE;SMC;VQ2100NY-5-X23-PNP-Q however I realised I needed to added a replace for ';' which I did and it worked for this example, however it doesn't work now for VALVE;SMC; VQ4200Y-5-Q. Maybe I should replace " " with a "-" at the start?

Comment: I'm making a function to do the delimiting for us. Have no fear, friend.

Comment: @ChengShi Okay, the function and routine are complete. Try using the new modified answer with the function I made, let me know if you run into any errors now :D

Comment: If you want me to help edit this code so it builds a table that a pivot table can be applied to, let me know :D

Comment: Wow, that is really cool! And works perfectly, like a charm! Now I'm trying to adapt it into something more user friendly, as at my organisation other people may need these tool and I won't always be here to do it. I thought about using an input box? But on the other side, I thought about trying to write something that would look for the title 'short text', and know that was where to search, and have an input box to enter what to search. I would then want the next blank column to display the results. I've looked around StackOverflow for help with this but nothing seems to have done it :/

Comment: I mean I'm really grateful for your help and you've already answer my question perfectly, so thanks so much in that respect! :)

Comment: I'm glad I could help you out so far! If this has answered your original question, could you mark it as such? As for your other question, we could go about it one of two ways: you could make a new question and give me the link and I'll start helping you out with that, or we could take the conversation off SO and I can help you personally.

Comment: Sure, thanks Tyeler. I'm just working on some other stuff, but one issue I have noticed, what if I want to search for a code like 11-456? Because the delimiting seems to cause an issue on that?

Comment: @ChengShi I've completely changed the function, and I've updated the main routine as well. I also commented on the parts you should change to tailor it to your needs. Nothing else needs to be changed. Don't touch the function, it's perfect as it is. This should get rid of your problem in finding search items that have delimiters inside them. :D

Comment: Hi, looks a lot more advanced! But unfortunately I'm get a subscript error for ReDim Preserve delInSearch(LBound(myDelimiter) To u) .Which is why I'm lost because you said it works for you? Thanks! :)

Comment: That was my bad, forgot to put that if statement in. On those two lines (the one you're getting the error on and the one right before it.) make it say `If t <> -1 Then Redim Preserve etc....` and on the other line do the same but with `u`. I updated the code in the answer if you want to see what I'm talking about. That will clear that error from happening :D

Answer (score 0):

You could still keep a formula based approach, using an array formula.  So, using the list being in e1:e4 and search criteria 1 in I1 and search criteria 2 in J1, I used the following

`=INDEX($E$1:$E$4,SMALL(IF((NOT(ISERROR(SEARCH($I$1 & " ",$E$1:$E$4))))+(NOT(ISERROR(SEARCH($J$1 & " ",$E$1:$E$4)))),ROW($E$1:$E$4)),ROWS($E$1:$E1)))`

and dragged down

[image]

Results can be seen in column G

---

Based on the comments, I've done the below array formula, this time, I've my data in A1:A5 and my search terms in D1 and D2.

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($A$1:$A$5 & " (" & $D$1 &")",SMALL(IF(NOT(ISERROR(SEARCH($D$1,$A$1:$A$5))),ROW($A$1:$A$5)),ROWS($B$1:$B1))),IFERROR(INDEX($A$1:$A$5 & " (" & $D$2 &")",SMALL(IF(NOT(ISERROR(SEARCH($D$2,$A$1:$A$5))),ROW($A$1:$A$5)),ROWS($B$1:$B1)-SUM(IF(NOT(ISERROR(SEARCH($D$1,$A$1:$A$5))),1,0)))),"<>"))
```

This looks as follows
[image]

Comment: Hi Nathan, I have tried your formula and your data set, and I am not getting the same results, simply #NUM! errors. Do you have any ideas of what to do regarding this please? Thanks for your contribution!

Comment: Did you put the data in as I have, and use CTRL SHIFT and ENTER for the formula as its an array formula.

Comment: Yes I did, however the results are still a little nonsensical, and not necessarily what I am after I think. I would want it to look in the first column for the word 'test' or 'show', and if it found either word, to return said word please.

Comment: Which is what it does, the 2nd image doesn't contain SHOW in row 3, where as the 1st image does.

Comment: Ah yes I see what it is doing now. However, I would want it to say 'test' next to 'test one', and either 'test' or 'show' next to testing show as it finds both words.

Comment: That's possible with a small change, the + in the formula, means OR, so it would just need to be replaced by a nested if way.  I'll have a look a bit later

Comment: @Nathan_Sav FYI ChengShi said in one of my comments that he has 800+ search words.

Comment: Ok, but there's no need to code to get to your image, this could be done via an array,

Answer (score 0):

This present two solutions:

***1. Method to work with long formulas in VBA***

***2. VBA code to classify all Materials Description at once.***

***1. Method to work with long formulas in VBA***

This formula is too long for VBA.

```
=IF(AQ2=1,IF(SUM(IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(Search!A$2, K2)), IF(COUNT((IF(CODE(MID(K2, SEARCH(Search!A$2, K2)-1, 1))>122, 1, "")), (IF(CODE(MID(K2, SEARCH(Search!A$2, K2)-1, 1))<65, 1, "")), (IF(SEARCH(Search!A$2, K2)-1<1, 1, ""))), IF(COUNT((IF(CODE(MID(K2, SEARCH(Search!A$2, K2)+LEN(Search!A$2), 1))>122, 1, "")), (IF(CODE(MID(K2, SEARCH(Search!A$2, K2)+LEN(Search!A$2), 1))<65, 1, "")), (IF((SEARCH(Search!A$2, K2)+LEN(Search!A$2)+1)>LEN(K2), 1, ""))), 1, 0), 0), 0))>0,Search!A$2,0),"")
```

To write long Formulas with VBA, we need to slice it down in several parts using variables.
So let’s first see the formula broken down by excel functions:

```
=IF(AQ2=1,
    IF(
        SUM(
            IF(
                ISNUMBER(SEARCH(Search!A$2, K2)),
                IF(
                    COUNT(
                        (IF(CODE(MID(K2, SEARCH(Search!A$2, K2)-1, 1))>122, 1, "")),
                        (IF(CODE(MID(K2, SEARCH(Search!A$2, K2)-1, 1))<65, 1, "")),
                        (IF(SEARCH(Search!A$2, K2)-1<1, 1, ""))),
                    IF(
                        COUNT(
                            (IF(CODE(MID(K2, SEARCH(Search!A$2, K2)+LEN(Search!A$2), 1))>122, 1, "")),
                            (IF(CODE(MID(K2, SEARCH(Search!A$2, K2)+LEN(Search!A$2), 1))<65, 1, "")),
                            (IF((SEARCH(Search!A$2, K2)+LEN(Search!A$2)+1)>LEN(K2), 1, ""))
                        ), 1, 0),
                    0),
            0)
        )>0,
        Search!A$2,0)
    ,"")
```

This formula has basically 4 parts:

•   It checks what you call the quick search in cell `AQ2` - Part 1

```
=IF(AQ2=1,
    IF(
        SUM(
            IF(
                ISNUMBER(SEARCH(Search!A$2, K2)),
```

•   Validates the character immediately before and after the word found:

Part 2 - before:

```
            IF(
                COUNT(
                    (IF(CODE(MID(K2, SEARCH(Search!A$2, K2)-1, 1))>122, 1, "")),
                    (IF(CODE(MID(K2, SEARCH(Search!A$2, K2)-1, 1))<65, 1, "")),
                    (IF(SEARCH(Search!A$2, K2)-1<1, 1, ""))),
```

Part 3 - after:

```
                IF(
                    COUNT(
                        (IF(CODE(MID(K2, SEARCH(Search!A$2, K2)+LEN(Search!A$2), 1))>122, 1, "")),
                        (IF(CODE(MID(K2, SEARCH(Search!A$2, K2)+LEN(Search!A$2), 1))<65, 1, "")),
                        (IF((SEARCH(Search!A$2, K2)+LEN(Search!A$2)+1)>LEN(K2), 1, ""))
                    ), 1, 0),
                0),
        0)
    )>0,
```

•   Then returns the result - Part 4

```
    Search!A$2,0)
,"")
```

Following the same logic I have modified your formula:

```
=IF(
IF(OR(
IFERROR(CODE(TRIM(MID($K2,IFERROR(SEARCH(Search!A$2,$K2),0)+
IF(IFERROR(SEARCH(Search!A$2,$K2),0)=1,0,-1),1))),0)
<65,
IFERROR(CODE(TRIM(MID($K2,IFERROR(SEARCH(Search!A$2,$K2),0)+
IF(IFERROR(SEARCH(Search!A$2,$K2),0)=1,0,-1),1))),0)
>122),0,1)
+
IF(OR(
IFERROR(CODE(TRIM(MID($K2,IFERROR(SEARCH(Search!A$2,$K2),0)+
LEN(Search!A$2),1))),0)
<65,
IFERROR(CODE(TRIM(MID($K2,IFERROR(SEARCH(Search!A$2,$K2),0)+
LEN(Search!A$2),1))),0)
>122),0,1)
<>0,"",Search!A$2)
```

Now we can clearly see the fundamental parts of the formula:

•   Getting the character immediately before:

```
IFERROR(CODE(TRIM(MID($K2,IFERROR(SEARCH(Search!A$2,$K2),0)+
IF(IFERROR(SEARCH(Search!A$2,$K2),0)=1,0,-1),1))),0)
```

•   Getting the character immediately after:

```
IFERROR(CODE(TRIM(MID($K2,IFERROR(SEARCH(Search!A$2,$K2),0)+
LEN(Search!A$2),1))),0)
```

Now we use variables to define the formula, but first in order to make the formula flexible so it can be applied with any reference let’s modify the *“hard coded”* references with strings that can be replaced with the references obtained at run time:
Substitute `$K2` with `#Cll` and `Search!A$2` with `#Srch`

The final code is something like this:

```
Sub Vba_Long_Formula()
Dim sCll As String, sSrch As String
sCll = "$K2"
sSrch = "Search!A$2"
Dim sFmlIni As String, sFmlEnd As String    'Formulas for the before and after characters
'Chr(10) is used to ease reading by breaking the formula by line
sFmlIni = "IFERROR(CODE(TRIM(MID(#Cll,IFERROR(SEARCH(#Srch,#Cll),0)+" & Chr(10) & _
    "IF(IFERROR(SEARCH(#Srch,#Cll),0)=1,0,-1),1))),0)"
sFmlEnd = "IFERROR(CODE(TRIM(MID(#Cll,IFERROR(SEARCH(#Srch,#Cll),0)+" & Chr(10) & _
    "LEN(#Srch),1))),0)"
Dim sFml1 As String 'Formula to be applied
sFml1 = "=IF(" & Chr(10) & _
    "IF(OR(" & Chr(10) & sFmlIni & "<65," & Chr(10) & sFmlIni & ">122),0,1)+" & Chr(10) & _
    "IF(OR(" & Chr(10) & sFmlEnd & "<65," & Chr(10) & sFmlEnd & ">122),0,1)<>0,"""",#Srch)"

    sFml1 = Replace(Replace(sFml1, "#Cll", sCll), "#Srch", sSrch)
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Raw Data Working").Range("AR2:AR4").Formula = sFml1

    End Sub
```

*Hope the above solves the problem with the long formula in VBA.*
[image]

***2. VBA code to classify all Materials Description at once.***

However, if you are using VBA then it’s more efficient to run the entire process using VBA to classify all the *Material Descriptions* with the corresponding *Brands*.

This code assumes the following *(change as required)*:

List of Brands starts at `'Search'!A2`

List of Materials Descriptions starts at `'Raw Data Working'!K2`

Output of Brands in column `'Raw Data Working'!AP`

```
Option Compare Text     ‘Must have this at the top of the module
Option Explicit

Sub Brand_Classification()
Dim aBrands As Variant, rMaterials As Range, rResults As Range
Dim rFound As Range, blFound As Boolean, sFound As String
Dim sMaterial As String
Dim lLastRow As Long
Dim vItm As Variant
Dim iAsc As Integer, bPos As Byte
Dim b As Byte

    Rem Set Array with Brands
    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Search")  'Change as needed
        lLastRow = .Columns("A:A").Cells(1 + .UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlLastCell).Row).End(xlUp).Row 'Change as needed
        aBrands = .Range("A2:A" & lLastRow).Value2  'Change as needed
    End With

    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Raw Data Working")    'Change as needed
        Rem Set Materials Description Range
        lLastRow = .Columns("K:K").Cells(1 + .UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlLastCell).Row).End(xlUp).Row 'Change as needed
        Set rMaterials = .Range("K2:K" & lLastRow)  'Change as needed

        Rem Set Brand Results Range
        Set rResults = .Range("AP2:AP" & lLastRow)  'Change as needed
        Rem Clearing prior results
        'rResults.ClearContents     '}Choose one of
        rResults.Value = Chr(39)    '}these options

    End With

    Rem Search for Brands in Materials Description
    For Each vItm In aBrands
        If vItm <> Empty Then
            With rMaterials
                Set rFound = .Cells.Find(What:=vItm, After:=.Cells(.Cells.Count), _
                    LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                    SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)

                Rem Validate Value Found
                If Not rFound Is Nothing Then
                    sFound = rFound.Address

                    Do
                        Rem Process Value Found
                        blFound = True
                        sMaterial = rFound.Value
                        For b = 1 To 2
                            Select Case b
                            Case 1
                                Rem Get Character Before Value
                                bPos = InStr(sMaterial, vItm)
                                bPos = -1 + bPos

                            Case 2
                                Rem Get Character After Value
                                bPos = InStr(sMaterial, vItm) + Len(vItm)

                            End Select

                            Rem Get Character
                            Select Case bPos
                            Case 0, Is > Len(sMaterial)
                            Case Else
                                Rem Validate Character
                                On Error Resume Next
                                iAsc = Asc(Mid(sMaterial, bPos, 1))
                                On Error GoTo 0
                                Select Case iAsc
                                Case 65 To 90, 97 To 122
                                    blFound = False

                        End Select: End Select: Next

                        Rem Write Results
                        If blFound Then
                            With rResults.Cells(1 - rMaterials.Row + rFound.Row)
                                If .Value = Empty Then
                                    .Value = vItm
                                Else
                                    .Value = .Value & ", " & vItm

                        End If: End With: End If

                        Rem Search Next
                        Set rFound = .FindNext(After:=rFound)
                        If rFound.Address = sFound Then Exit Do

    Loop: End If: End With: End If: Next

    End Sub
```

[image]

Suggest to read the following pages to gain a deeper understanding of the resources used:

[Do...Loop Statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/gg278815.aspx), 
[For Each...Next Statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/gg264596.aspx),
[On Error Statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg251688.aspx), 
[Option keyword](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg278518(v=office.15).aspx), 
[Range Object (Excel)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff838238.aspx), 
[Select Case Statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/gg278665.aspx),
[Variables & Constants](http://www.excelfunctions.net/VBA-Variables-And-Constants.html), 
[With Statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/gg264723.aspx),

Comment: Hi, thanks for the fantastic answer so far, however I am getting an error running your VBA code for the second solution. It hits a type mismatch error for 'for each vItm In aBrands', and tracing back I can't really see what's wrong, any ideas?

Comment: HI are you getting this error for a particular value of all the time?

Comment: When updating the range with Brands how did you change this part: `aBrands = .Range("A2:A" & lLastRow).Value2`?

Comment: Hi, yes this has solved the error thanks. However I noticed it doesn't pick up words at the end of the text, only in the middle. For example, it could fine the word 'SMC' when it was in the middle of the text, just not when it was at the end?

Comment: I'm using a work around, of simply adding ";" to the end of each material description, but it's a bit messy so if it's a simple code tweak would you know it?

Comment: Ok let me look into it and will come back to you... I though you have the answer already...

Comment: I decided to create multiple searches for multiple different things. But unfortunately I can't say that both of you have answered me :(

Comment: If that is the case how is that you have select already an answer {%>]. Btw  the adjustment is done. The code is now including the Brand when is the last word. try and let me know...